# Does `tf.data.Dataset.map` preserve the input order?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Does `tf.data.Dataset.map()` preserve the order of input elements?
Specially when `num_parallel_calls > 1`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, `Dataset.map()` produces transformed elements in the same order that the original elements appeared in the input, for all values of `num_parallel_calls`.